# Cancelling out norms of a vector

Tags: svm

I was going through the derivation of the geometric margin for an SVM and I was confused about one step.

We have
$w^T(x^{(i)} - \gamma^{(i)}\frac{w}{\|w\|}) + b = 0$

We then solve for $\gamma$

$\gamma^{(i)} = \frac{w^Tx^{(i)}+b}{\|w\|}$.

But I didn't understand how the $\frac{\|w\|}{w}$ became $\frac{1}{\|w\|}$.

I know $\|w\| = \sqrt{w^Tw}$, but I don't see that could cancel with $w$ in any way.

Comment: It doesn't seem that this could be correct algebraically assuming your first equation is correct.

Comment: @MichaelChernick I updated the first equation to the original one that I saw before I tried to simplify it. Maybe I did something wrong while simplifying then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with:
$$w^T\left(x^{(i)} - \gamma^{(i)}\frac{w}{\|w\|}\right)+ b = 0$$

Apply distributive rule:

$$w^Tx^{(i)} - \gamma^{(i)}\frac{w^Tw}{\|w\|} + b = 0$$

Assuming $\|w\|$ denotes the usual [Euclidean norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm), we have $w^Tw = \|w\|^2$ hence:
$$w^Tx^{(i)} - \gamma^{(i)}\frac{\|w\|^2}{\|w\|} + b = 0$$
Simplify, divide by $\|w\|$, and add $\gamma^{(i)}$ to both sides:
$$ \gamma^{(i)} = \frac{w^T x^{(i)} + b}{\|w\|}$$